# Is there a way to have module hierarchy closed by default?

Tags: haskell, haddock

With multi-package projects, it would be great to have the module hierarchy closed, i.e not expanded, by default. Is this possible to configure?

Alternatively, can one add custom JavaScript to the generated index.html, e.g via a command line argument? There is the `--lib=<dir>` argument but can't quite make out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```bash
script_text="$(cat my.js)"
sed 's/</body>/<script>'"$script_text"'</script></body>/g' docs/index.html > docs/index-collapsed.html
```

If there is an actual blessed way to include additional JavaScript in the Haddocks' module listing page, please do post it as an answer!